Snowflake - Tasks with multiple stream_has_data conditions
I have a task that is set as follow:
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK db.schema.task_name
WAREHOUSE = WH_NAME
USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = XXXX
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0,30 * * * * America/Santiago'
WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1') OR SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2') OR SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_3')
AS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
    value_1 INTEGER;
    respose STRING;
    stream_result resultset DEFAULT (<query_1>);
    query_result resultset DEFAULT (<query_2>);
    c1 CURSOR FOR query_result;
BEGIN
    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
          value_1 := row_variable.count;
    END FOR;
...

I have two questions, first, is there any way in which after the tasks enter his code because one of those streams has data, theres a way to know which one is it the one that fulfilled the condition? I wouldn't like to use a nested if for that, maybe theres a more direct way,
second, if i replace that <query_1> with something like 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.schema.stream_1 and the result is stored in the variable stream_result, the stream is erased?
Edit, full script thats failing:
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK db.schema.task_name
WAREHOUSE = XXXX
USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = XXXX
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0,30 * * * * America/Santiago'
WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1') OR SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2') OR SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_3') OR SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_4')
AS 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  response_string STRING;
  result BOOLEAN;
  stream_result resultset;
  query_result resultset;
  c1 CURSOR FOR stream_result;
  c2 CURSOR FOR query_result;
BEGIN
 IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1'), 
     stream_result := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_1 ORDER BY process_date), 
 IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2'),
     stream_result := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_2 ORDER BY process_date),
 IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_3'),
     stream_result := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_3 ORDER BY process_date),                
 IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_4'),
     stream_result := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_4 ORDER BY process_date)
,null))));

FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
  query_result := (SELECT stg.flg_registry FROM db.schema.load_status stg WHERE row_variable.process_date = stg.process_date);
  FOR row_variable_2 IN c2 DO
    IF (row_variable_2.flg_registry = 1) THEN
      result := true;
    ELSE    
      result := false;
      BREAK inner_loop;
    END IF;
  END FOR;
  IF (:result = true) THEN
    response_string := (call sp_1(row_variable.process_date));
    RETURN(:respuesta);
  ELSE 
    RETURN('process date ' || row_variable.process_date || ' is not full loaded');
  END IF;
END FOR;
    
END;
$$;

Error:

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 10 at position 7 unexpected
'('. syntax error line 10 at position 30 unexpected '('.

Thanks

Hi - A stream advances the offset only when it is used in a DML transaction, and a SELECT is not a DML transaction

If you want to know which stream(s) had data then add logic in your SQL to use SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA and write the result somewhere you can subsequently read

Hi @NickW, if inside the sql code i do something like this: BEGIN
IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1'), stream_result := (SELECT processing_date FROM SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1') ORDER BY processing_date), IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2'), stream_result := (SELECT processing_date FROM SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2'), .. To know which one is the one that has data is ok right? And the data of the stream should't be deleted, right?

@NickW IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1'), resultado_stream := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_1 ORDER BY process_date), IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2'), resultado_stream := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_2 ORDER BY process_date), IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_3'), resultado_stream := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_3 ORDER BY process_date), IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_4'), resultado_stream := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_4 ORDER BY process_date),null))));

This is giving me this error: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 10 at position 7 unexpected '('. syntax error line 10 at position 30 unexpected '('.

And if i do only: IFF(SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1'), resultado_stream := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_1 ORDER BY process_date),null); Gives me the exact same error: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 10 at position 7 unexpected '('.
syntax error line 10 at position 30 unexpected '('. I don't know if its enabled to use the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('') inside an IFF condition

If you can’t debug this typo on your own then I’d suggest you raise it as a new question and include the full code for your task creation script

@NickW edited above with complete task script
